# Get data of type without pattern match on all data contructors

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

Is there a way to make abstraction of the data type and just use the values?

`data Color a = Blue a | Green a | Red a | Yellow a | Magenta a deriving (Show)`

Something like :

```
calcColor :: Color a -> Color a -> Maybe a
calcColor (_ x) (_ y) = Just $ x + y
```

It doesn't have to be necessarily in the function declaration.
One option I was thinking was to have something like `fromJust` but even that feels a little redundant.

```
fromColor :: Color a -> a
fromColor (Blue t) = t
fromColor (Red t) = t
fromColor (Green t) = t
fromColor (Yellow t) = t
```

---

### Edit - added context and more clarifications

From the way I managed to question it, the title might look like a duplicate question.

I'm not that sure, but that is for the community to decide.
I pretty new to Haskell so maybe my question looks stupid but still I think it's a valid case because I actually have this situation.

@FyodorSoikin, @leftaroundabout Your answers helps me, but partially. I'll try make explain better what exactly I would like to achive.

I want to think at the Color type like a category (let's say G), the colors beeing elements of the G, 
and I also have phones that come in different colors. The phones category (let's say H).

Now I have I try to come with a way to make use of the morphisms (functions) of the G category using a functor in the H category or the other way around.
For example : determine the future stocks of a color type based on the sales of phones.

I want to understand to what extend I can create a types like Color to have the advantages of a type ustead of using a string value.

Comment: If all your constructors have the exact same shape, a better representation would be a product: `data Hue = Blue | Green | Red; data Color a = Color { hue :: Hue, value :: a }`

Comment: Reopening, on the grounds of your clarifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do a hack like

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, toList)

data Color a = Blue a | Green a | Red a | Yellow a | Magenta a 
  deriving (Show, Foldable)

fromColor :: Color a -> a
fromColor c = case toList c of
   [ca] -> ca
   _ -> error "Impossible, `Color` has only one field."
```

But I agree with Fyodor Soikin's comment: why have the `a` field in each constructor in the first place? Just factor it out

```
data Hue = Blue | Green | Red | Yellow | Magenta
data Color a = Color { hue :: Hue, value :: a }
```

Comment: And if typing `Color Blue x` instead of just `Blue x` is an issue, we always have pattern synonyms that can be used to provide the shorter interface.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, it looks like you are looking for a basic vocabulary for dealing with `Color`. That can be provided both by class instances and by special-purpose functions.

A `Functor` instance, for example, allows you to change the `a` value in a `Color a` independently of the color itself:

```
data Hue = Blue | Green | Red | Yellow | Magenta
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Color a = Color { hue :: Hue, value :: a }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Color where
    fmap f (Color h a) = Color h (f a)
```

```
GHCi> test1 = Color Red 27
GHCi> fmap (2*) test1
Color {hue = Red, value = 54}
```

Two brief notes:

1. The things I'm suggesting here can be done equally as well with your four-constructor `Color` type or with [leftaroundabout's single-constructor one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61392226/2751851). The latter, though, should be easier to work with in most situations, so I'll stick with it.
2. The `DeriveFunctor` extension means you almost never have to write a `Functor` instance explicitly: turn it on by adding `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` to the top of your file and then just write:

   ```
   data Color a = Color { hue :: Hue, value :: a }
       deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
   ```

Another thing you might want to do is having a `Hue -> Colour a -> Maybe a` function, which would give you a way to use operations on `Maybe` to filter the `a` values by their attached hue:

```
colorToMaybe :: Hue -> Color a -> Maybe a
colorToMaybe chosenHue col
    | hue col == chosenHue = Just (value col)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

```
GHCi> test1 = Color Red 27
GHCi> test2 = Color Red 14
GHCi> test3 = Color Blue 33
GHCi> import Data.Maybe
GHCi> mapMaybe (colorToMaybe Red) [test1, test2, test3]
[27,14]
GHCi> import Control.Applicative
GHCi> liftA2 (+) (colorToMaybe Red test1) (colorToMaybe Red test2)
Just 41
GHCi> liftA2 (+) (colorToMaybe Red test1) (colorToMaybe Red test3)
Nothing
```

These are just rather arbitrary suggestions. The specifics of what you'll want to define will depend on your use cases.